# what does private[wikipedia] mean in sacla?

Tags: scala, access-modifiers

I am new to scala and don't know what does `private[wikipedia]`mean,could anyone please tell me?Is it a generic type?

```
package wikipedia

import scala.io.Source

object WikipediaData {

  private[wikipedia] def lines: List[String] = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to scope the privacy of a given object. So `private[wiki]` means only code defined within `wiki` has access to `lines`.

See here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package/

Answer (score -1):

private[packageX] means the following method/class/object/constructor is accessible only from within that package - in this case syntax is the package name, and this constructor is only accessible from other code inside syntax package.

Comment: In `private[X]` `X` can be not only a package.

Comment: Currently literal copy of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35929185/5249621 [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)